# What is a series of a journal?

Tags: journals

When looking at the Journal of the London mathematical society in Mathscinet, I notice that the system displays two different journals under this name:

- Journal of the London Mathematical Society
  and
- Journal of the London Mathematical Society. Second Series

Similarly, there are:

- Annals of Mathematics
  and
- Annals of Mathematics. Second Series.

Sometimes there are even more series. There is for example
Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society. Third Series

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some journals restart their volume numbering on occasion. This reset marks a start of a new "series". In order for a reference to point to a unique paper, it is then common to specify both series and volume numbers (though series can typically also be inferred from the publication year). In the case of Annals of Mathematics, a new series was started the first time the [journal moved universities](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3258/69504).

Comment: I always found it strange that when the Bulletin of the Amer. Math. Society restarted its volume numbering in 1979, the new volumes were not called "Second Series" but "New Series" (MathSciNet writes "Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)"), as if the editors didn't think about the burden this places on future editors who would ever create another series after this: Brand New Series? New New Series?

Comment: @KCd is that really relevant? The year disambiguates the series. If you cite a paper from 1982, it is obviously from N. S.

Comment: @Davidmh my point was that the decision to use the term "New Series" puts future BAMS editors in an awkward situation if they want to create another volume series after "New Series".  Surely the folks who thought it was worth renaming the volumes as "New Series" could not have thought "We want to restart the numbering again at 1 but nobody after us will ever want to do that."

Answer (score 4):

The January 1904 Proceedings was the first in the "Second Series". In it [on page 1](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-1.1.1-s) was a

> #### Notice Concerning the Second Series of "Proceedings."
>
> THE  following  statement  made  by  the  President,  Prof.  H.  Lamb,  at the   meeting   of  the   Society,   held   on  June   11th,   1903,  is   reported   in *Proceedings*, Vol. XXXV.,  pp.  460, 461:—
>
> > "The  first  four  volumes   of  *Proceedings*  contain  the  papers  of eight  and  a  half  years   (January,  1865–June,  1873).    Vols. V.–XXIX. correspond   with  the   Sessions  1873–1898,  one  with  each  Session. Vols.  XXX.–XXXV.  are   edited   in   accordance   with  the  rule  that   the 'Volumes   shall  contain   as  nearly   four  hundred  pages   as  may   be found   convenient,  provided   that  each  volume  shall   begin  with   the Report   of   Proceedings   at   a   meeting,  not   necessarily   an  Annual General  Meeting.'    These  volumes  contain  the  records  of  proceedings at  meetings,  followed  by  the  papers  read  at  the  meetings,  and   they also  contain    Appendices  in  which  are  Notes  and   Corrections   and Obituary   Notices   of   deceased  members.    The   Council   has   decided that  in  future  the  records   of  proceedings   at  meetings  and  matter   of the  kind  previously  placed  in  Appendices  shall  be  collected   at  the beginnings   of  volumes   and  shall   have  a  different   pagination   from that   of  the  papers,  and  that  the  records   of  proceedings  at  meetings shall  be  issued   for  a   Session   at   a  time   in   the   earliest   completed volume  after  the  end   of  the  Session.  …    The  volumes  are   to  contain  as  nearly five hundred  pages  as  may  be  found  convenient."

To summarize — the London Mathematical Society changed their rules governing the Proceedings, enough that they decided to clearly separate the Second Series from the original.